# How to compute extra pay in night shifts and on sundays

Tags: mysql, datetime, calendar, shift, overlapping

I did a table in MySQL storing start and end times of working shifts in datetime type. I need to calculate two things from them (in MySQL). First of all, how many minutes someone has worked in given shift between 10pm and 6am, as well as how many minutes someone has worked on a sunday. Sunday should have priority over those night times, and it shouldn't count those sunday mornings twice.

Thank you in advance.

D.

I tried this btw, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT *,
IF(DAYNAME(start)=DAYNAME(end),
    IF(TIME(start)<='6:00:00' AND TIME(end)<='6:00:00',TIME(end)-TIME(start),
        IF(TIME(start)>='22:00:00' AND TIME(end)>='22:00:00',TIME(end)-TIME(start),
            IF(TIME(start)>='6:00:00' AND TIME(end)<='22:00:00',0,
                IF(TIME(start)<='6:00:00' AND TIME(end)<='22:00:00','6:00:00'-TIME(start),
                    IF(TIME(start)>='6:00:00' AND TIME(end)>='22:00:00',TIME(end)-'22:00:00',NULL)
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    IF(TIME(start)<='22:00:00' AND TIME(end)<='6:00:00','2:00:00'+TIME(end),
        IF(TIME(start)<='22:00' AND TIME(end)>='6:00:00','8:00:00',
            IF(TIME(start)>='22:00:00' AND TIME(end)<='6:00:00','24:00:00'-TIME(start)+TIME(end),
                IF(TIME(start)>='22:00:00' AND TIME(end)>='6:00:00','24:00:00'-TIME(start)+'6:00:00',NULL)
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS ExtraTime FROM `work`
```

Comment: What programming language are you using to send the query to MySQL? Ad@m

Comment: At the moment, none. I wanted to do it in MySQL. But if there isn't an easy solution, PHP would be also OK.

Answer (score 1):

minutes worked:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `start_time`, `end_time`) FROM ... WHERE DAYOFWEEK(`start_time`) != 1
```

minutes worked on Sunday:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `start_time`, `end_time`) FROM ... WHERE DAYOFWEEK(`start_time`) = 1
```

Comment: That would be nice, if the shift really started at – let's say 10pm. But in reality it starts at 9:45pm and ends at 6:15pm. Or starts at 2:55am and ends at 11:05am. Those between 10pm and 6am will be multiplied by 1.25. Again, those on Sunday will be multiplied with 1.25 as well. But not with both.

Comment: @MDV: I'm not sure I follow your request; I didn't understand the logic. If you want to check for night shifts, I assume you might be having some flag in your database. If not, you can do something like WHERE `\`start_time\` > '21:00:00 00:00:00'`. The above query gives you some start and I think you may try to build some logic upon it. If it doesn't work, feel free to share your query on SO; the community will be eager to help.

Comment: Can you see what I tried to do using an insane amount of IFs? It doesn't work the way it is supposed to, though. Would be of help if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, try this code (warning: it hasn't been tested):

```
<?php
$regularPay = 100; //100 dollars a day
$weekendPay = $regularPay + ($regularPay / 2); //150 dollars over weekend
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysqli_select_db("dbname");
$pay = date("w")==0 or date("w")==6 ? $weekendPay : $regularPay; //0=Sun, 6=Sat
$query = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO pay SET employee='John Smith',pay='$pay'");
?>
```

Simply replace the strings with the appropriate values for your computer.

Ad@m.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't really help. Shifts rarely start and end at the same time, but the company is required to pay additional 25% on Sundays and 25% at night between 10pm and 6am – regardless when one has started to work. Extras can't be combined, though.

Comment: @MDV Sorry, I can't really help there... I'm not very good at calculating shifts in maths... :/ Ad@m

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess I'm a looser when it comes to this kind of stuff, too.